How does Vertex AI Search of Agent Builder evalute data index usage when import data from Cloud Storage?
I have created a datastore importing about 2GB of pdf documents from Cloud Storage.
The billing dashbords shows that the data index usage of Vertex Search is only 0.16GB month.
The data index pricing of Vertex Search could be an issue for implementing any Enterprise Search solution based on Agent Builder without knowing how Agent Builder evalutes data index usage when import data from Cloud Storage.
